# How to Control Length of mesh line by percentage - Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, constraints, mathematics

This may be a bit complicated to ask but hopefully this makes sense.

I have a geometry node creating horizontal blinds for a window. I would like to control the opening of the blinds by a percentage. So 0% would be fully closed, ie. the length of the mesh line would equal the needed count divided by the window height (controlled by the Mesh Line Offset). At 100%, the blinds will be fully opened with the slats completely horizontal and the mesh line would equal the count times the thickness of each slat.

Maybe I have been working on this for too long and I am making it more complicated than it needs to be  but what can I do to achieve this function? I can see the math to get the right lengths but I don't know how I can create a functions that allows me to change the percentage to something like 35% open. Any thoughts?

https://blend-exchange.com/b/mOGOENa2/

[image: Example of blinds at 30% open]

This image shows what I am looking for.  As the bottom rises, then the slats stack and follow each other.

[image: My project picture]

Comment: it would have been nice if you would have shown us what you tried so far - because now it just "looks like" you are looking for someone who does your work. So providing a blend file how far you have been would be great for 1) showing you tried really something 2) make it easier for us to help to just extend that instead having to build everything on our own

Comment: and second comment: instead of describing with hundreds of words, most often a good sketch with some annotations is much more worth.

Comment: and third comment: this site allows exactly one question. This makes sense because "normally" you could only summarize a title for one theme. But you are allowed to open as many questions as you like

Comment: Sorry about that. Still new to this platform. The one question rule makes sense. My biggest issue is really the first main one.  For the line mesh control I am looking for something like this picture here
https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fp%2FHome-Decorators-Collection-White-Cordless-Faux-Wood-Blinds-for-Windows-with-2-in-Slats-36-in-W-x-48-in-L-Actual-Size-35-5-in-W-x-48-in-L-10793478184576%2F206300994&psig=AOvVaw2gb8P0dvM9xUUgKR0cBYxD&ust=1697599002977000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCJDNmaGP_IEDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mathematically a very simple task (and i only answer that one specific question, please open other questions for your other problems, thx):

so by this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

The only "challenge" you might have here is, that you have to know, that Blender internally in most cases uses radians to calculate, not degrees. But mapping values can easily be done with the map range node.
In this case map range node maps between percentage and radians (0-100/0-pi/2)

Comment: Oh crap. I thought I had pasted in the link to my file.  My node tree is a bit messy and it was hard to get all the right nodes I wanted to check.  Here is my Blend file. I definitley am not looking to mooch from other people. I just have a complicated problem with a complicated mind that can't figure this out. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=mOGOENa2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/mOGOENa2/)